# PHP Fatal error: Cannot declare class Stripe\\Stripe, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I am using armember plugin to create a form and also use stripe plugin to integrate the payment gateway. so I have two stripe plugin one for armember and one for another class so. I am getting this error:

> PHP Fatal error: Cannot declare class Stripe\Stripe, because the name is already

please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

It is looking like Stripe class name exists in both plugins and we can't use two classes with the same name in same module/directory.

To resolve it, customize one plugin i.e replace the class name and it's all reference in the plugin from Stripe to MyStripe, it will make the class unique and then you can use both classes without any conflict

Comment: I faced this issue in my SugarCRM project, I have no link regarding this but I resolved it by modifying the class name. 

In your case, open your plugin directory in any IDE like NetBeans, visual studio, etc, there is an option of find and replace in IDE, find Stripe and replace it with MyStripe, it will change your class name as well as all the references where it is used.

But remember just do it in one plugin only.